# How can I fix the error '0xc00000e - "A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed"' on Windows 10 startup without the installation DVD?

Tags: windows, boot, windows-10, ssd

I recently upgraded my system with an SSD to boot from. I cloned my old drive onto the SSD and now when I try to boot it, I get the following error:

[image: https://gyazo.com/a9927c8d13104f613f71d31b799c801f] 
*(Sorry for the poor image quality, my phone isn't amazing)*

I am trying to boot into Windows 10 with this issue, not Windows 7 (as I have seen many people have this issue with 7) and I do not have any installation media. The keybinds it comes up with on this screen just refresh it.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into trouble when cloning an HDD to an SSD for a friend's laptop. The cloned SSD wasn't booting Windows 10. As I was using my PC to clone, I had access to a working Windows 10 install, and could use [EasyUEFI](https://www.easyuefi.com/index-us.html).
EasyUEFI was suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54527110/3397114).

1. Download and install the program
2. Select "Manage EFI System Partition" (image of
   a pie graph and a man)
3. Select "Rebuild EFI System Partition" (image
   of a pie graph and a hammer)
4. Select the disk with a broken Windows installation
5. Specify the boot partition (containing Windows install, usually a large
   partition)
6. Specify the EFI partition (should be smaller partition, FAT32
   formatted)
7. Click "Rebuild"

It should complete quite quickly. Then you can then boot into the repaired Windows install.

Comment: This did the trick for me after several attempts. Thank you.

Comment: this should be marked as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

When you cloned the disk it got another disk ID number I suppose (or you accessed SSD after cloning while it was attached to OS on hard disk).

Disk ID + partition ID are used to completely address a partition - value stored in BCD for a partition device.

To fix issue you have to repair BCD on SSD - fix default boot entry to point to OS on SSD disk. **Amend device and OS device for default loader using bcdedit on BCD on SSD.**

If system partition (active partition or EFI System partition) on SSD is not mapped you have to map it!

Alternatively you could use Visual BCD Editor for comfortably fixing BCD on SSD, just drop BCD from SSD on [Visual BCD Editor](http://www.boyans.net) icon (after installing the tool) and then make the changes to "ApplicationDevice" and "OSDevice" by click and selection.

Note: the error is NOT "winload.exe is missing or corrupt" BUT 0xc00000e - "A required device isn't connected or can't be accessed"! Heading should changed.